# Have you used any Project Management software for Bloggers or News Media Website?

Tags: pm-software

We are three partners and have also hired couple of interns.

Our project is a article based website. Or more simply its a blog or News Media Website.

We would like to discuss on article topics or any other ideas and keep working on them and delegate specific task to each other. It would also help us to keep track of each others progress.

Can you suggest what kind of project management software (web based) should be used to collaborate and delegate tasks.

Comment: Due to site scope change, we're closing tool recommendation questions. See http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/351/we-will-be-closing-all-tool-recommendations-within-2-weeks

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping the scope of your tool search to something that:

- allows easy task assignment
- allows comments and discussions on task assignments
- shows dependency and timeline views of assignments
- shows to-dos/overdos

Then I would recommend the SaaS-based product [Wrike](http://www.wrike.com/).

That list is not all that you can do, but it does those specific things very well, and it is quite lightweight and easy to use.

Given a list of tasks, it also produces some great visualizations of the work, such as:
[image: this nice chart]

It's worth at least [taking a tour](http://www.wrike.com/tour.jsp) to see if it would work for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Edit Flow for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/) and its [editflow.org](http://editflow.org/) site. Its focus is editorial workflow. This has a few advantages over a generic project tool:

- using the language and conventions of publishing news, like an editorial budget.
- integration with WordPress increases accountability since tracking and control are just part of the CMS interface everyone uses, seen every day.
- integration with WordPress also ties management and the editorial conversations to the actual deliverables; you can see progress as it happens.

The blurb:

> Edit Flow empowers you to collaborate with your editorial team inside WordPress. We've made it modular so you can customize it to your needs:
>
> - Calendar - A convenient month-by-month look at your content.
> - Custom Statuses - Define the key stages to your workflow.
> - Editorial Comments - Threaded commenting in the admin for private discussion between writers and editors.
> - Editorial Metadata - Keep track of the important details.
> - Notifications - Receive timely updates on the content you're following.
> - Story Budget - View your upcoming content budget.
> - User Groups - Keep your users organized by department or function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [Trello](http://www.trello.com) will be a perfect fit. It is free, you can setup required flow, assign tasks to each other, discuss them. There are various examples how Trello can be used. It is a general purpose collaboration software.

Wrike or any other similar tool will be an overhead for sure.

[See Trello board in action](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c)

Comment: We use Trello and Wrike in conjunction (although not connected), because they do different things, specifically because Trello does not have the task tracking and dependency visualizations.

Comment: I don't think any PM software should have Gantt Chart inside, sorry. Trello is the best choice.